# how to connect a client-server written in different language

Tags: c#, go, tcp, server

How to connect a client-server written in different language?
for example I have a server written in GO and a client written in C# they are both using Tcp/IP.
is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is that even possible?

Sure and it's done on a regular basis when web clients written in C, C++, go, Python, Perl, C#, Ruby etc communicate with web servers written in C, C++, Javascript, Ruby... whatever. All they need is to agree on a common protocol to use on the "wire", like HTTP, HTTPS etc.

Comment: but how to connect them?

Comment: @lyger he told you, you need to have both sides agree on "messages" then you write the code in each of the languages to write and read the messages on a TCP/IP connection.